# Reading from a string using sscanf in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, scanf

I'm trying to read a string in a specific format

```
<ahref="/teams/spain/real-sociedad-de-futbol/2028/">RealSociedad</a>
```

this is one example of string and what I want to extract is the name of the team.

I've tried something like this,

```
houseteam = sscanf(str, '<ahref="%*s">%s</a>');
```

but it does not work, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) like you did in your post above to do this for you.  Even though your post says to use `sscanf` and from the comments in your post, you'd like to see this done using `regexprep`.  You would have to do this using two nested `regexprep` calls, and you can retrieve the team name (i.e. `RealSociedad`) like so, given that `str` is in the format that you have provided:

```
str = '<ahref="/teams/spain/real-sociedad-de-futbol/2028/">RealSociedad</a>';
houseteam = regexprep(regexprep(str, '^<a(.*)">', ''), '</a>$', '')
```

This looks very intimidating, but let's break this up.  First, look at this statement:

```
regexprep(str, '^<a(.*)">', '')
```

How `regexprep` works is you specify the string you want to analyze, the pattern you are searching for, then what you want to replace this pattern with.  The pattern we are looking for is:

```
^<a(.*)">
```

This says you are looking for patterns where the beginning of the string starts with a `a<`.  After this, the `(.*)">` is performing a **greedy** evaluation.  This is saying that we want to find the **longest** sequence of characters until we reach the characters of `">`.  As such, what the regular expression will match is the following string:

```
<ahref="/teams/spain/real-sociedad-de-futbol/2028/">
```

We then replace this with a blank string.  As such, the output of the first `regexprep` call will be this:

```
RealSociedad</a>
```

We want to get rid of the `</a>` string, and so we would make another `regexprep` call where we look for the `</a>` at the end of the string, then replace this with the blank string yet again.  The pattern you are looking for is thus:

```
</a>$
```

The dollar sign `($)` symbolizes that this pattern should appear **at the end of the string**.  If we find such a pattern, we will replace it with the blank string.  Therefore, what we get in the end is:

```
RealSociedad
```

Comment: @SamuelNLP - You're welcome :)  I didn't think you'd accept my answer, as you wanted something with `sscanf`.  Still, thank you very much... and this was the rep I need to get to the next tier :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. So, `%s` stops when it finds a space.

```
    str = regexprep(str, '<', ' <');
    str = regexprep(str, '>', '> ');
    houseteam = sscanf(str, '%*s %s %*s');
```

This will create a space between my desired string.

Comment: I would have suggested you use regular expressions, but your post said you wanted `sscanf`, which is why I didn't reply!  Either way, good answer.

Comment: Can you give me an example anyway?

Comment: With regular expressions or `sscanf`?

Comment: Are all of your strings like the above format?  Basically, will you see `<a href>...</a>`?

Comment: yeah, but I don't want `"/teams/spain/real-sociedad-de-futbol/2028/"` this part, which is not always the same.